# Getting all fields with a custom attribute, and automatically saving and loading them based on given enum

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

---

**NOTE #1:** This is in Unity, so I mention a scene, if you don't know what that is, don't worry about it, it doesn't apply too much to this question.

---

**NOTE #2:** I have looked at multiple other stack overflow posts on this subject, but they were very confusing to me, and I don't have enough reputation yet to comment, so I couldn't ask for clarification on how to use the code solutions given.

---

I have two custom attributes that I made, `AutoSave` and `AutoLoad`, and I want to get a List of all of their data, like the name of the field, the data that the field stores, no matter the type, and the stuff that the attribute call is given, for `AutoSave`: a string for the file path, a string for the scene name, a enum for the save type (which stores whether or not it will save during the beginning, the end, or when a method is called with the name of this field) and an enum for the settings (which stores whether it will write over what is currently there, or add to what is there (which is a work in progress)). And for `AutoLoad`: a string for the file path, a string for the scene name, and a enum for the load type (which is the exact same as the `AutoSave` attribute).

The code that I saw that I would like to use to sort and store is this:

```
Type type = typeof(AutoLoad);
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in type.GetProperties())
{
    var props = from p in this.GetType().GetProperties()
            let attr = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AutoLoad), true)
            where attr.Length == 1
            select new { Property = p, Attribute = attr.First() as AutoLoad };
}
```

I am not sure if this is right, and I dont know how to implement, sort and store this data. If I am reading this properly, this is LINQ querying, which I am not familiar with. And I am brand new to Attributes, so if I am missing something, please let me know, and an explanation of how this code works would be nice as well.

I would store these in 6 `Dictionary<string, List<WhateverTypeICanStoreTheseAs>>`, the string being the scene name, the List being a list of every of this data that has that particular scene name attached. 3 dictionaries for saving, 3 for loading, each one having 1 dictionary for the beginning, 1 for the custom times, and 1 for the end. If there is a better way to store this data, please let me know!

If anyone is familiar with attributes, thanks for the help!

---

EDIT:
Here is my current implementation of the above code, it returns nothing when calling ToString, and returns 1 when checking outer count, and returns 0 when checking inner count.:

```
public static List<List<AutoSType>> GetAllOfAttribute()
{
    Type type = typeof(AutoSave);
    List<List<AutoSType>> objs = new List<List<AutoSType>>();
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in type.GetProperties())
    {
        var props = from p in prop.GetType().GetProperties()
                    let attr = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AutoSave), true)
                    where attr.Length == 1
                    select new AutoSType { Property = p, Attribute = attr.First() as AutoSave };
        objs.Add(props.ToList());
    }

    return objs;
}
```

Using the method:

```
List<List<AutoSType>> autoSObjs = AutoSave.GetAllOfAttribute();
Debug.Log(autoSObjs.Count);
if(autoSObjs.Count > 0)
{
    Debug.Log(autoSObjs[0].Count);
}

foreach(List<AutoSType> a in autoSObjs)
{
    foreach(AutoSType b in a)
    {
        string temp = b.Attribute.ToString();
        Debug.Log(temp);
    }
}
```

ToString override:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"{filePath}, {sceneName}, {saveType.ToString()}, {saveSettings.ToString()}";
}
```

Using the attribute:

```
[AutoSave("", "Main", AutoSave.SaveType.Beginning, AutoSave.SaveSettings.AddTo)]
public int endDate;
[AutoSave("", "Main", AutoSave.SaveType.Beginning, AutoSave.SaveSettings.AddTo)]
public string startDay;
```

Comment: It's not clear from all of this what the actual question is. Does the code you have work? If you have the data and you're asking how to store it, then all the details about how you got the data are probably irrelevant. Or does this code not work as expected? In that case can you be specific about what doesn't seem to work correctly?

Comment: Is there anything you can tell us about these classes? Are they all `MonoBehaviour`s, for instance? What technique are you currently using to find the instances you're interested in saving? What have you already tried for finding instances?

Comment: @ScottHannen I have edited the post to answer your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to find all instances of `AutoSave` and do something based upon that. But look at your code.

If we translate your `GetAllOfAttribute` to psuedo-code we get

1. Get the type definition for AutoSave
2. Initialize a list to save our `List<List<AutoSType>>`
3. Iterate all of the properties on AutoSave (*wait, why?*)
4. For each property on autoSave, get the properties on the `PropertyInfo` class, but only if that property on PropertyInfo has an `[AutoSave]` on it (*Pretty sure we just went WAY off the rails here*)

Instead you want to

1. Get all types in your assembly
2. For those types, filter those to the ones that contain a property with `[AutoSave]` on it, then operate on that type/property.

Also, as with just about anything using reflection this is going to be resource-intensive so ensure you only run it once, or once per scene. You can possibly add a class-level attribute that it can key off of to avoid iterating properties on classes you don't want looked at like creating an `[AutoSaveEnabled]` you can attach to the class.

```
foreach (Type type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
{
    if (type.GetCustomAttribute<AutoSaveEnabled>(true) != null)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in type.GetProperties())
        {
            AutoSave attr = prop.GetCustomAttribute<AutoSave>(true);
            if (attr != null)
            {
                // I found the attribute!!!
                // At this point, type is the class I'm looking at, prop is the decorated property, and attr is the instance of `[AutoSave]`
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just able to implement your code, however, it is still returning nothing. I made a custom attribute called ```AutoSaveEnabled```, applied it to a class like this ```[AutoSaveEnabled]``` and added fields that have ```[AutoSave]``` but it didnt return anything. When debugging all the properties in the ```(foreach PropertyInfo prop in type.GetProperties())```, I get all the properties that a gameobject has example: enabled, transform, gameObject, tag, name. None of the variables were returned.

Comment: @BtStudios you're calling `.GetProperties()` so make sure the variable you're looking for IS a property. `public string startDay;` is a field, not a property. Either change it to a property with a getter/setter or update the code to use `FieldInfo field in type.GetFields()` instead. If you want to expose it to the Unity3D editor you'll probably want to leave it as field and simply change how you're looking for it unless Unity sees properties now (it didn't used to when I was working with it a few years ago). You can also keep the existing `GetProperties` and just add another check for fields.